# nodejs memory allocation failure

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

I was using decryption to decrypt "MySql" data. I got the below issue:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>   31681 ms: Mark-sweep 654.1 (666.5) -> 492.5 (509.8) MB, 267.5 / 0.0 ms
>   [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
>   31839 ms: Mark-sweep 492.5 (509.8) -> 492.2 (506.8) MB, 157.5 / 0.0 ms
>   [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
>   31985 ms: Mark-sweep 492.2 (506.8) -> 492.2 (497.8) MB, 146.2 / 0.0 ms
>   [last resort gc].                                32122 ms: Mark-sweep
>   492.2 (497.8) -> 492.2 (497.8) MB, 136.8 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
>   <--- JS stacktrace --->

What is it regarding and how to fix it,

Thanks in advance

Comment: How big is the data you're trying to decrypt?  You need to figure out what is using too much memory in your node.js app and/or, you need to increase the amount of memory you node.js app has available to it.  FYI heap snapshots will help you figure out what your memory is being consumed by.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alllocate more memory to your script by using the following argument to node: --max_old_space_size=x

Example:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8000 yourscript.js
```

This will allocate about 8GB to your script. Eventually this is still not sufficient and you should decrypt your SQL in smaller chunks and make use of your physical drive instead of RAM memory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: For anyone needing this setting in a container, you can also set `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8000` as an environment variable

Comment: I have the same problem in the GitLab runner build and set this parameter but it doesn't work! `- export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
    - npm install --legacy-peer-deps --no-shrinkwrap --update-binary
    - CI=false npm run-script  build:prod`

Comment: `NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"` should be `NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=8192"`. Swap the dashes for underscores in the flag key.

Answer (score 9):

**Proper solution**

Something is using too much memory in your node.js app. This is usually bad sign and requires investigation in long term. To find out the exact piece of code, which does this - you may want to check out node.js profiling techniques. Some article about this https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/

**Fast solution**

In some cases fast workaround is what we want. For such cases, as correctly pointed out by Cryptic Pug - we can increase JS memory allocation limit. There are few options how to do so (based on your needs)

1. pass argument to `node` directly

   ```sh
   node --max_old_space_size=4096 app.js
   ```
2. use environment variable

   ```sh
   NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
   node app.js
   ```
3. use [`.npmrc`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) file. Put following in `.npmrc` local or global file

   ```
   node-options=--max_old_space_size=4096
   ```

   and run your script

   ```sh
   node app.js
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I was caught in the same issue. When I run the project, it was React js Project, I got the same error.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
...
JavaScript heap out of memory
```

etc
After 2 hours of research and connecting with my peers, I downgrade my node js version from **v14.15.4 to v14.15.3**. Restart my PC, And then delete my node_modules and yarn.lock file, and reinstall my packages, run my project, and the error is gone.
Maybe it will help some others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered a similar error. After days of trying out all solutions online without success, I finally found what worked for me. I had the Node js LTS version of 16.7 installed on my machine. Upgrading to the current version of node js 18.0 solved the issue.

Comment: Upating Node.js worked for me too.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

Answer (score 0):

I was caught in the same situation. When I ran my ReactJS project in my WSL (Windows 11), I received the same problem.

The other alternatives did not work for me.

As mentioned in [How to solve JavaScript heap out of memory error](https://sebhastian.com/javascript-heap-out-of-memory/) I resolved the issue in my **WSL** using **ZSH** by adding the line next lint to my `.zshrc` file.

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 #4GB
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem but by removing globally installed electron and installing electron locally for my project this error disappears.